# How to get a specific value from a database?

Tags: prolog

I want to get the weight of an user who is saved on usersData

```
 usersData([]).
:-dynamic usersData/1.

 buildUser(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training, User):-
 User = user(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training).
```

and compare his current weight with the new one. An user is identified by his id, so on his predicate I receive both Id and New Weight, but before printing that it has updated, I want to give a feedback printing whether he has lost or gained weight.

```
updateWeight(Data):-
   write('What's your id?: '), nl,
   readNumber(Id),nl,
   write('Current weight: '), nl,
   readNumber(NewWeight),nl,
   setWeight(Id, NewWeight), nl,nl,
   write('Weight updated!'),nl,nl,
   write('Press Enter to return to the main menu'),
   readString(_),
   begin(Data).
```

I want to do something like:

```
if(newWeight > weight) {
  weightDif = newWeight - weight;
  System.out.println('You have gained ' + weightDif + 'kg');
} else {
  weightDif = weight - newWeight;
  System.out.println('You have lost ' + weightDif + 'kg');
}
```

I appreciate all the answers, literally tried everything so far and couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog's **indexing mechanism** restricts the set of clauses to be tried, while searching solutions to a goal, by using goals' instantiated arguments as database **keys**. Thus, representing users as sets of clauses can be much more efficient than represeting them as lists of terms.

Assuming all identifiers are **distinct** and you only want to access users whose identifiers are **known**, to access a specific user:

- **set of clauses representation** requires approximately constant time.
- **list of terms representation** requires linear time.

So, a better representation is, for example:

```
:- dynamic(user/7).

% user(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training)

user(id1, ann, 22, 60.2, 1.69, p1, t1).
user(id2, bob, 29, 80.5, 1.81, p2, t2).
user(id3, coy, 31, 70.5, 1.74, p3, t3).
```

If you really need to retrieve all users as a **list of terms**, then you can use the following predicate:

```
users_data(List) :-
    findall( user(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training),
             user(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training),
             List ).
```

For example:

```
?- users_data(L).
L = [user(id1, ann, 22, 60.2, 1.69, p1, t1), user(id2, bob, 29, 80.5, 1.81, p2, t2), user(id3, coy, 31, 70.5, 1.74, p3, t3)].
```

With this suggested representation, the solution to your problem can be obtained with the following code (assuming that `Id` and `NewWeight` are correctly instantiated):

```
set_weight(Id, NewWeight) :-
    retract(user(Id, Name, Age, OldWeight, Height, Plan, Trainning)),
    assert(user(Id, Name, Age, NewWeight, Height, Plan, Trainning)),
    Dif is abs(NewWeight - OldWeight),
    (   NewWeight > OldWeight
    ->  format('You have gained ~1f Kg', [Dif])
    ;   format('You have lost ~1f Kg',   [Dif]) ).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- set_weight(id1, 61.9).
You have gained 1.7 Kg
true.

?- set_weight(id2, 79.5).
You have lost 1.0 Kg
true.

?- set_weight(id3, 72.7).
You have gained 2.2 Kg
true.

?- set_weight(id5, 72.7).
false.

?- listing(user).
:- dynamic user/7.

user(id1, ann, 22, 61.9, 1.69, p1, t1).
user(id2, bob, 29, 79.5, 1.81, p2, t2).
user(id3, coy, 31, 72.7, 1.74, p3, t3).

?- users_data(L).
L = [user(id1, ann, 22, 61.9, 1.69, p1, t1), user(id2, bob, 29, 79.5, 1.81, p2, t2), user(id3, coy, 31, 72.7, 1.74, p3, t3)].
```

Comment: @xiao  If this is the answer you was looking for, please, mark it as accepted!

Comment: they didn't accept the answer to their previous question. Will they do it this time? Or will they just accept both? Or will they get their homework handed in with the help they got, never to be seen again? Time will tell. Until then, remember: if you are doing this for the points, you will have a bad time. If you are doing it because you think this helps people, you are going to have even worse time.

Comment: @TA_intern I think you're right! However, I don't know whether they accepted answers to previous questions or not, as this is the first time I answer a question from them (at least as far as I remember). I don't do it for points, I do it as hobby (but I think acknowledgement is important). And as for you ... I'm curious, why do you do it?

Comment: "I don't know whether they accepted answers to previous questions or not" you can easily check that by looking at their profile. Cannot say whether it is a good or a bad idea to do this kind of background check on users before bothering to answer them.